# Windows Inter Process Synchronizization Like Events?

Tags: c++, windows

I read something about Pipes and Sockets, but none of those seem to fulfill my needs.

I have a GUI program. The user can control it, tell it to stop, start, etc.

I have another daemon (CLI) program which is run by my GUI program when the user clicks the Start button.

The daemon app does some processing, and I want it to send information to the GUI app to show to the user. But I can't run my GUI app on a `while` loop to wait for that information.

Is there any better way to do this? Like events or callbacks?

Comment: A pipe or socket would work just fine. Simply use it in a worker thread, or at least in non-blocking/asynchronous mode, so you don't block your UI thread while reading data from the daemon.

Comment: You can do this using windows messages, using `FindWindow` and `SendMessage` APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events or semaphores are probably what you want.

See this answer: [Can Events be Inter-Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625504/can-events-be-inter-process)

For simple triggering of events, it should be sufficient. Named pipes or shared memory mapped files are better used for transferring larger amounts of data.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Just a quick question to save time from googling, do I need the functions OpenEvent, WaitForSingleObject and also SetEvent? EDIT: Seems like it. Thanks.

Comment: @jordancedrick Honestly, using synchronisation objects is not a trivial subject, and to say what you need without really knowing your application, or your level of experience is not realistic. The subject matter can occupy month long courses. Googling it for examples and design patterns is probably a useful exercise anyway.